# Is it possible for a website, by knowing the public IP only, to detect the exact smartphone device I'm using?

Tags: cookies, ip, detection, smartphone, simcard

If with the same smartphone device I surf to one website (each time with a different IP, different SIM card and no saved cookies or cache), is it possile to detect that I'm using the same device? If so, how exactly?

Comment: user agent string

Comment: @schroeder How can I bypass the browser's user agent string?

Comment: on a computer, there are utilities that will re-write it for you - you will have to look to see what's available on the mobile device that you are using.

Comment: I will just develop a new webrowser myself then, thank you.

Comment: Note that there are "browser fingerprinting" issues you will have to address in your custom browser. Should be easy to fiddle with, though.

Comment: If you're on Android you can give mobile Firefox a try. I think it lets you change user agent. See https://panopticlick.eff.org/.

Comment: if the website can see your mac address then they can. Since mac address can't be know from website. It is not possible to know the same device or not.

Comment: @sbsangpi I think browser fingerprinting works without mac address

Comment: @NeilSmithline fingerprinting will only identity the person, not the phone! right?

Comment: Google browser fingerprinting. See https://panopticlick.eff.org/. It says my phone has a unique fingerprint.

Comment: Funny enough, developing your own browser would make you **more** unique, not less.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is impossible for a website to detect the nature of your device through your IP address. There is no information within the IP address that indicates the nature of the device. The physical part in the IP address is just an address of the machine.

To detect your device, a website must implement other techniques such as [OS fingerprinting](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/OS_fingerprinting) and [device fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint).

Comment: Exactly. FYI: here's a recent flaw in the HTML5 Battery Status
API that allows websites to fingerprint a device: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/616.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can uniquely identify you, most of the time, based on the headers that your browser sends.

See https://panopticlick.eff.org/

There is also http://samy.pl/evercookie/ which can set non-regular cookies, which are very hard to delete.